# How do I find out where a program has been installed?

Tags: installation, sublime-text

The first ever time I installed Ubuntu was 45 minutes ago. Bearing this in mind, please answer me slowly!

I've been trying to install Sublime Text 2 by following [these instructions](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/907). (First Method)

First, I navigated to my root directory:

```
cd ~
```

And then I followed the steps detailed in the link above:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get --purge remove sublime-text*

sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

I think everything's worked properly. However, I have no idea where Sublime Text is installed, or how I can even run it. (I'm hoping I can just click on it!)

Comment: When I am not sure about a command: tab autocompletes command so my 1st guess would be "sub"+{tab} and see if it works ;)

Comment: Excellent! 'subl' was the command I needed to launch sublime text...still would like to know where it's installed though. Will be using that tab for the rest of my career probably :)

Comment: `which subl` will tell you where the binary is located. `dpkg -L sublime-text` will list all the files the package installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `whereis` command. For example, in your case:

```
whereis sublime-text
```

Also `locate` can be useful in this sense. Use it like this:

```
sudo updatedb && locate sublime-text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find out where on your system the binaries are placed by shell command:

```
dpkg -L sublime-text | grep bin/
```

But without researching you can just try

```
sublime_text
```

in a terminal.

If you want the program in your start menu, you can crate a file in `/usr/share/applications` called `sublime.desktop` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Sublime Text
Comment=Sublime Text 2
Exec=sublime_text
Icon=/opt/sublime/Icon/256x256/sublime_text.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=true
```

As in your link described. But maybe this file is already made. This new menu entry can be found in "Menu -> Accessories".